# Ruby metaprogramming to achieve dynamic methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, instance-variables

Want to achieve the following code using metaprogramming.

```
@resource = {}
@voters = {}
@is_upvoted = {}

def resource(comment)
  @resource[comment.id]
end

def voters(comment)
  @voters[comment.id]
end

def is_upvoted(comment)
  @is_upvoted[comment.id]
end
```

How can I create these methods using ruby metaprogramming and access the hash?

Can you tell me what is wrong in my code ?

```
['resource', 'voters', 'is_upvoted'].each do |attribute|
  define_method("#{attribute}") do |comment|
    instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", comment.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit seems redundant:

```
@resource = {}
@voters = {}
@is_upvoted = {}
```

Since you're already looping an array to do your metaprogramming.

You might try something like:

```
class Foo 

  %w(
    resource
    voters
    is_upvoted
  ).each do |attr_sym|
    define_method attr_sym do |comment|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_sym}", {}) unless instance_variable_get("@#{attr_sym}")
      instance_variable_get("@#{attr_sym}")[comment.id]
    end
  end

end
```

Which I believe will give you methods roughly like:

```
class Foo 

  def resource(comment)
    @resource ||= {}
    @resource[comment.id]
  end

end
```

Personally, it seems not great to me to have `comment.id` in your method. Because what if someday you want to use a different attribute (or something else altogether) as the `key`?

So, I think I would do:

```
class Foo 

  %w(
    resource
    voters
    is_upvoted
  ).each do |attr_sym|
    define_method attr_sym do |key|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_sym}", {}) unless instance_variable_get("@#{attr_sym}")
      instance_variable_get("@#{attr_sym}")[key]
    end
  end

end
```

Now, it seems like you're going to want an easy way to set key-value pairs on your instance variable, so I guess I would try something like:

```
class Foo 

  %w(
    resource
    voters
    is_upvoted
  ).each do |attr_sym|
    define_method attr_sym do |key=nil|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_sym}", {}) unless instance_variable_get("@#{attr_sym}")
      hsh = instance_variable_get("@#{attr_sym}")
      return hsh[key] if key
      hsh
    end
  end

end
```

In which case you should be able to do (assuming you have a `@comment` variable that responds to `id`):

```
@comment.id 
 => 1 
foo = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x000056536d7504b0>
foo.resource 
 => {}
foo.resource[@comment.id] = :bar
 => :bar 
foo.resource 
 => {1=>:bar}
foo.resource[@comment.id]
 => :bar
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me what is wrong in my code ?

It's doing the equivalent of this:

```
def resource(comment)
  @resource = comment.id
end
```

`instance_variable_get` would be a better choice.

Comment: How can I access the hash using this ?

Comment: NameError (`@resource[13739]' is not allowed as an instance variable name)
Got this error after using  instance_variable_get

Comment: @vikas95prasad: of course, the square brackets and the number are not part of the instance variable name, so don't put them there.

Comment: @mrzasa this is how i used it and it works 
instance_variable_get("@#{attribute}")[comment.id]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used it and it works

```
['resource', 'voters', 'is_upvoted'].each do |attribute|
  define_method("#{attribute}") do |comment|
    instance_variable_get("@#{attribute}")[comment.id]
  end
end
```